# Get the value of a field to do an if statement Twig

Tags: theming, 8

I am trying to generate a PDF with *Entity Print*. Until then all is well.

In my Twig page, I try to make conditional displays. But I can’t get the conditions to work.

I render my fields using ***{{ content.field_custom }}*** and that also works fine.

But the condition don't work , when I do something like :

```
{% if content.field_custom == 'John' %} ...
```

or

```
{% set field = content.field_custom %}
{% if field == 'John' %}
   <p>Hello</p>
{% endif %}
```

I need to do this in the fields twig template, can someone help me?

Many thanks

Comment: Your condition not working because content.field_custom value not equal Jonh. variable content.field_name is render array. So all values is includes string of template field render. Examples "<div>Jone</div>".  You have to use strip tags for that. or using node.field_name.value for condition.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.

    {% if (content.field_custom|striptags) == 'John' %}

That didn't work for me though unfortunately. How to use it ?

Comment: Because it is not a string, it is a render array. It will never just equal John.

Comment: try with content.field_custom|render|striptag or just node.field_custom.value

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. It seems to be working but I'm still having a problem that I hadn't anticipated. 
My field is fed one by one token so, node.field_custom.value returns me the token ([current-user: field_custom: value]) and not the value of the token.
How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the [Twig Field Value](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_field_value) module, which provides a `field_value` filter that you can apply directly to a field:

`{{ content.field_name|field_value }}`

Also, while this doesn't specifically answer your question, I would be remiss not to mention the handy and useful [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module. It rocks! :)